# Is there anything in Python like a try-finally except it still raises exceptions normally?

Tags: python, syntax, finally

Suppose I want to run some function in Python, ensuring that whether it fails or not some cleanup code is always run. Something like this:

```
try: some_function()
finally: cleanup()
```

Ok, simple enough. But hold up! If any exceptions occur in the try block, they'll be **suppressed.** So really this construct did **more** than I wanted. All I really wanted to do was make sure some cleanup code runs after the function whether it finishes successfully or not. I still want any exceptions which occur in my function to happen *normally.* Perhaps that would look something like this:

```
do: some_function()
finally: cleanup()
```

Of course, that isn't real Python code. The actual way which I've found to do this is like follows:

```
try: some_function()
except Exception as error: raise error
finally: cleanup()
```

Eww, gross. I'm adding an extra line to **re-throw** an exception which I wanted to just happen normally in the first place. And additionally the stack trace now has an extra line in it showing the `except Exception as error: raise error` bit. This seems less than ideal to me, but it also seems to be the only way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

### So is this really the way I'm supposed to go about this?

If yes, then I have a further question: **Why doesn't Python have a dedicated construct for simply ensuring some block of code runs whether some other block succeeds or not?**

As far as my small mind is concerned, this whole idea has little to do with exception handling, since I don't actually want to keep exceptions from occurring where they normally would in the stack trace. Therefore, forcing people to use a try-except-finally construct seems just weird to me.

Comment: "If any exceptions occur in the try block, they'll be suppressed" - uh, no? `finally` doesn't do that.

Comment: `finally` is already exactly the mechanism you're looking for. You've just got some weird, wrong idea about what it does, maybe because you `return`ed in a `finally` once and suppressed exceptions that way, or because you thought that `try` rather than `except` is the part that catches exceptions.

Comment: [Here, watch a `finally` not suppress anything.](https://ideone.com/CtTqdL)

Comment: Sounds like some first world problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Python *does*!

```
try:
    1/0
finally:
    print("Hello, world!")
print("This will not print.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so as @user2357112 pointed out it looks like I somehow had the wild misconception that the **try** part of a try-except-finally construct is what catches exceptions. If anyone else gets confused similarly... it's the **except** bit that does the catching. Pretty obvious after some thinking, but hey everyone has brain farts sometimes.